# view sets throwing pagenotfound! found Django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Getting page not found error, trying *DRF*, I am trying these viewsets but so far error as mentioned thanks in advance!

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('organisation_list/',OrganisationList.as_view()),
]
```

**Routes**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'list_organisation',OrganisationViewSet)




class OrganisationViewSet(ViewSet):

    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []

    queryset = Organisation.objects.all()
   
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def list_organisations(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print('working')
        data = self.queryset
        serializer = OrganisationSerializer(data,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
```

**error**

```
 "GET /list_organisation/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3548
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the view `list_organisations` was defined as a custom action, the actual url for it is:

```
list_organisation/list_organisations
```

If you want `list_organisation/`, just change the view to `list`:

```
class OrganisationViewSet(ViewSet):
    ...
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('working')
        data = self.queryset
        serializer = OrganisationSerializer(data,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
```

Comment: bu then what is `url_path` used for

Comment: That is to customise the url for a custom action. By default it will be the view name. But whatever value it gets, it will always be after `list_organisation/`, so something like `list_organisation/my_custom_url_path`